# How can we solve the polynomial equation $f(x)=0$?

Tags: soft-question

Consider the equation

$$f(x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots + a_{n-1}x+a_n=0.$$

In the cases that $n\leq 4$ we can find a formula describing the complex solutions to this equation using functions $\sqrt[1]{}, \ \sqrt[2]{}, \ \sqrt[3]{},\ \sqrt[4]{}\ $. In the case that $n\geq 5$ it is proved that the "sqrt" functions are not enough to describe the solutions.

Question: How can we find the complex roots of this equation? n is possibly greater than 4.

Comment: You should explain what you mean by "solve". What class of operations are you permitting? (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Solving_through_Bring_radical for context)

Comment: @Yemon, as an example  consider $x^6+2x^5-3x^4+12x^2-x+17=0$. How can we find the roots of this equation? How about the same equation but with irrational  coefficients?

Comment: @hamidrezanemati: Yemen Choi's point stands; what matters is not the example, but what tools you allow. Are you allowing infinite series representations for solutions, elliptic functions, infinite recursive algorithms (like Newton's method), oracles (like the theory of Turing machines)?

Comment: You might ask what sort of representation of solution do you allow? Do you want the answer to 5 decimals, or only exact answers in terms of elementary functions, or something else?

Comment: This paper explains how computer algebra systems handle this: https://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~graebe/ComputerAlgebra/Publications/ACA-98.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Newton's method always works (with clever initial conditions): http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/NewtonInventiones.pdf

Comment: @arsmath What do you mean by "you can do better"?

Comment: @arsmath But the OP did not ask for real roots, and even if s/he had, Sturm's algorithm is quite a bit slower than Newton's method (when they both work...)